# Pro and cons of oauth2 authentication data blob persistency approach

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security

I plan to use the "Spring Security OAuth" framework as the base of an OAUTH2 authorization server with access tokens, refresh tokens and codes features.

By default the framework uses java serialization to store additional authentication data (column 'authentication') in the database tables oauth_code, oauth_access_token and oauth_refresh_token.

i would like to start a discussion to find out the pros and cons of this approach and i am interested to know if there are plans to change this.

**cons:**

- framework version upgrades are not possible if the new version can't deserialize data from the previous version
- unneeded data: the blob may contain data that is not needed at all (e.g. the original request)
- sensitive data: the blob may contain sensitiv data like user credentials
- data redundancy: data is stored 3 times for the tables listed above
- data analysis: authentication data cannot be selected by plain SQL statements

**pros:**

- extension: data can be extended without schema migration in a easy way (good to start from scratch)

**alternatives to 'blob' approach:**

- store authentication data in a separate table (e.g. oauth_authentication) with data columns for every piece of information that is really needed (e.g. user id, client id, scopes, ...) and a foreign key from oauth_code, oauth_access_token and oauth_refresh_token.

What could be the negative consequences of the alternative?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

@Dennis: I am totally agree with you. Currently I am going through this blob persistency issue. As spring has upgraded security version, it is causing us n number of problems. Your first point in cons : framework version upgrades are not possible if the new version can't deserialize data from the previous version. I think this should be handled elegantly in OAuth2 Framework.